# How to sort a list of list

Tags: apex, list, collection

I am trying to figure it out how to sort a list of list using apex, like for example :

> **Input :** [[5, 'text1], [1, 'text2'] , [12, 'text3]]
>
> To obtain and ascending ordered list like that :
>
> **Output:** [ [1, 'text2'], [5, 'text1] , [12, 'text3] ]

I have researched around and I have found a way in Java but really nothing clear about apex. Any help would be really appreciated it! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement [Comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_comparable.htm) interface for your custom class and determine your rule in `compareTo` method.

```
public class ListItem implements Comparable {
    public Integer first {get; set;}
    public String second {get; set;}
    
    public ListItem(Integer first, String second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        ListItem compareToItem  = (ListItem)compareTo;
        return this.first - compareToitem.first;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ListItem firstItem = new ListItem(5, 'text1');
ListItem secondItem = new ListItem(1, 'text2');
ListItem thirdItem = new ListItem(12, 'text3');

List<ListItem> listItems = new List<ListItem>{firstItem, secondItem, thirdItem};
listItems.sort();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!.